# Can I able to detect object with Intel(R) UHD graphics 620?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, pycharm

I want to detect objects using a camera, I have installed PyCharm also TensorFlow CPU version but I still need GPU version of Tensorflow for object detection using Cuda, but when I was installing that I found that it works with NVIDIA graphics card only. Now I stuck on this.

1. Does anyone have an idea of how to detect real-time video objects using Intel(R) UHD graphics 620 card?
2. Also, I have found OpenCV as a source to detect the object but I don't have an idea how to proceed with that?
3. One more approach with Raspberry Pi I have searched for but it is still failing to detect the live video object.
4. How about the ARM Mali-T720 GPU can I use to detect the object?

Comment: if you are using the integrated graphics that come alongside with the CPU then there is no need to install the GPU version, as tensorflow will depend on your cpu, gpu version works only with nividia and amd.
If you are willing to train a model i recommend you by getting a nividia gpu or AMD if you are well informed about the config you have to do in order to get it work.
The VRAM of the gpu depends on how much data are you willing to feed your model in the training phase.

Comment: Yeah, I got your point. But by using a laptop should I able to connect the external GPU like NVIDIA and AMD?

Comment: if your laptop supports that then yes you can do it,